# SwiftUI. Как сделать динамический time label внутри сообщения?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Как сделать в iOS приложении используя SwiftUI time label внутри ячейки сообщения такими, чтобы в зависимости от количества строк метка со временем находилась либо рядом с текстом, либо под текстом. Так реализовано в *Telegram* и *What's App*

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot2]

есть такой пример кода:

```swift
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                if isFirstMessage, !isCurrentUser {
                    Text(name)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(Colors.message.color)
                }
                HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Text(text)
                        .foregroundColor(Colors.message.color)
                    timeCheckMarkOverlay
                }
            }
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 12)
        .padding([.top, .bottom], 7)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .background(isCurrentUser ? Colors.currentUserMessage.color : Colors.anotherUserMessage.color)
```

[image: 3]
сейчас выглядит так

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Такой же вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1415471/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-view-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-whatsapp-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-swiftui